# Angular filters clickable result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters

I am using a  nice snippet of code from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Onza/cWVrV/) working as expected, however, when I want to add a href to link  each result to another page of my app, I struggle with finding a proper syntax. 
Thanks for your help.

Here is what I have so far in my html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="searchController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Type here" class="search_all_inputfield">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchText " href="#">
                <td >{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

EDIT: WORKING SOLUTION - amended HTML replacing table presentation with DIV :

```
<div data-ng-controller="searchController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Type here" class="search_all_inputfield">
        <div ng-repeat="dish in dishList" href="#">
            <a href="#path/to/url"><div>
                <span>{{item.id}}</span>
                <span> / </span>
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </div></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add a link to your data

```
$scope.items = [
    {id:1, name:'John', link:'home'},
    {id:2, name:'Steve', link:'about'},
    {id:3, name:'Joey', link:'contact'},
    {id:4, name:'Mary', link:'links'},
    {id:5, name:'Marylin', link:'blog'}];
```

then you can create a link using ng-href

```
<td><a ng-href='{{item.link}}'>{{item.name}}</a></td>
```

Comment: well, this can work, but as data will eventually come from webservices, i am looking for a way to generate dynamic url from html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you post an example?

Comment: you 'll see i have found a solution and update my post with the syntax embedding  the url in the html